# CSS selector to bold only labels without child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a basic html form where `label` tags are used to define field names and where `label` tags are used around checkboxes so that a user clicking on the text next to a checkbox also selects the checkbox.

```
<label>Valid?</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Yes
</label>
```

What CSS is the best practice so that my field name is bold ("Valid?"), but my checkbox descriptor is not bold?

I have tried several variations adding different `:not` and `:empty`, but I'm not hitting the right selector - either both are bold or neither are bold. I know my :empty isn't working since the text element messes that up, but there must be a simple way to only bold labels that have only text elements.

```
label:empty {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z77tq8bs/

Comment: You can't wrapper Yes or Valid? in <span>?

Comment: I have control over html, but trying to stay standard as possible - this is part of an MVC .NET site, so trying to let helpers do most of the work without having to add custom attributes or templates on top of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the next sibling selector, like this:

```
label {
   font-weight: bold;
}

label + label { 
    font-weight: normal
}
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cLuhznb/

Comment: Not a bad approach, but any way to have the solution be order-independent? I sometimes have validation elements between the 2 elements (this is a simplified example from a .NET mvc view that uses a validation message in between the elements). I guess i could apply the bold to the first child of the parent...

Comment: You can put a specific class for bold text, like a helper class, and use it on the label that you want to be bold, too. It's not a bad practice and avoids specificity issues.

Comment: I could either add a span that I always bold or just make a bold class and add it to the desired labels, but I'm trying to avoid having to make adjustments to every label so that I can rely on a global style if possible. The + selector is very interesting though...haven't tried that before.

Comment: Yes. For this case, this is the best option. But you said you maybe have some elements between the labels. Anyway, you could also add this elements to the css using element + label approach, like the example.

Comment: I modified your solution slightly by having `* + label` as the second selector to account for the elements between potentially. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The `:empty` pseudo-class targets elements that have no children (not even a space).

The pseudo-class can be used in the following way: http://jsfiddle.net/3z1pnv71/.

HTML:

```
<label></label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Yes
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label:empty:before {
    content: "Valid?";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

EDIT: It's also possible to keep all the textual elements in HTML and use the following approach, if it is suitable: http://jsfiddle.net/cqugufex/.

HTML:

```
<label data-text = "Valid?"></label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Yes
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label:empty:before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, but I don't think I want to embed my view field labels into my stylesheets. +1 for concept though :)

Comment: I agree.  The meaning of the content is best ascertained on the basis of HTML that surrounds it.  However, it is possible to keep all of the content within HTML and still use the suggested approach: http://jsfiddle.net/cqugufex/.

Answer (score 0):

Found a few solutions to this, both of which work because the label descriptor is always the first label within the parent element, and any checkboxes are subsequent labels

Solution 1: `first-of-type`

```
label:first-of-type {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Solution 2: `first-child`

```
label:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I still haven't found a solution that finds if a label has only a text element, but this at least works for most cases.

Comment: You really should be using modifier classes for this sort of thing. For example: <label class="label label--bold">label</label>. This allows for much more manageable code and long term growth. Just my two cents.