# CSS selector for label without child elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

First of all the solution in that question: [CSS selector to bold only labels without child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564756/css-selector-to-bold-only-labels-without-child-elements) does not solve my issue.

I have labels with text only and others with text and child input, select and textarea form's elements.

i.e:

```
<label class="control-label">State
            <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Choose..</option>
                                ...
                            </select>

        </label>
```

and other like:

```
<label for="defect" class="control-label">Error</label>
```

I need to set `white-space: nowrap` to labels that has no child HTML elements only and as the above question answers stated, I tried the following:

```
label{
  white-space: nowrap; /* Label without HTML*/
}
label + label {
  white-space: normal; /* Label with HTML */
}
```

However, it does not work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no easy way to do this.

Comment: Can you modify the markup?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this with a selector. Would a js solution be acceptable?

Comment: @hungerstar Yes I can.

Comment: @jfeferman It is not very critical to complicate it with Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be adding a class to the element and using CSS to format it accordingly.

`label.empty {
white-space: nowrap;
}`

**Link to the documentation:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

The other comment points to using `:empty` but in your case the `<label>` contains some text and doesn't apply as empty

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no solution using CSS selectors. The solution proposed by @FabioPontes to control via an additional class name would be the most straight-forward.

Following is a javascript solution that verifies for an element's child nodes and applies a `white-space:nowrap` if (1) there is only one child node and (2) this node is of type text. Please view [node types](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp).

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("control-label");

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].childNodes.length == 1 && elements[i].childNodes[0].nodeType == 3) {
    elements[i].style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

  <label class="control-label">State - we need a really long text to check if the white-space nowrap is actually working so lets place this text here.
    <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Choose..</option>
    </select>

  </label>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">

  <label for="defect" class="control-label">Error - we need a really long text to check if the white-space nowrap is actually working so lets place this text here.</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The option to add a class has already been suggested by Fabio Pontes and is a good one, but if you don't want to add classes, here are a couple options.

The first thing you could do is modify your markup to wrap each `label` in a `div` and then leverage the `:only-child` pseudo selector. In order for this to work, you'll have to include the `select` element as a sibling of the `label`, rather than as a child of it.

```css
.control-label-wrapper label:only-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-label-wrapper">
  <label class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut tellus massa. Phasellus dictum mollis lobortis.</label>
  <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose..</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="control-label-wrapper">
  <label for="defect" class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut tellus massa. Phasellus dictum mollis lobortis.</label>
</div>
```

Another option which may not require modifying your makup at all is to use an [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp). Perhaps you're already using an attribute for all these childless labels. The example HTML in your question suggests you may be.

```css
label[for="defect"] {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<label class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut tellus massa. Phasellus dictum mollis lobortis.
  <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose..</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label for="defect" class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut tellus massa. Phasellus dictum mollis lobortis.</label>
```